# Target particular site among Firebase multiple site hosting for react js and using github actions?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github, hosting, github-actions

So I have a react js and I am using firebase to host the site. And I have created a project named "parentproject" having multiple sites "site1" "site2".
And I am using GitHub actions to detect push on either of my 2 branches "prod and dev". So, when I push into prod branch I want to deploy on "site1" and when I push to dev branch I want to deply on  "site2".
I am also using github workflow. My firebase configs are :

```
.firebaserc

{
  "projects": {
    "default": "site1"
  },
  "targets": {
    "parentProject": {
      "hosting": {
        "prod": ["site1"],
        "dev": ["site2"],
      }
    }
  }
}

firebase.json

{
  "hosting": {
    "target": "prod",
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My yml file for push branch looks like:

```
# This file was auto-generated by the Firebase CLI
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - prod
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '14'
      - run: npm ci
      - run: CI=false npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_SECRETKEY }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: parentProject
        env:
          FIREBASE_CLI_PREVIEWS: hostingchannels
```

Every time I push to prod, my site gets deployed on default firebase hosting page, not  "site1". Any suggestion are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a field called "target" where you can setup the specific site to deploy, more about it on the documentation of the firebase github action: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy#target-string

```yaml
(...)
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_SECRETKEY }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: parentProject
==>       target: "<site id here>"
        env:
          FIREBASE_CLI_PREVIEWS: hostingchannels
```

You have to add also the field "site" on the firebase.json, like:

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "target": "prod",
==> "site": "<id of the site in the firebase projet>",
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```